# Как создать Resource.rc в vs code?

Tags: c++

Я добавил **resource.h** и **Resource.rc** в папку **resourse**

resource.h:

```
#define MAIN_ICON                       103
```

Resource.rc:

```
MAIN_ICON               ICON                    "discord.ico"
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "headers/stdafx.h"
#include "headers/resourse/Resource.rc"
int  main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    std::cout<< "Hello World!";
    BOOL a = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(MAIN_ICON), RT_ICON);
    return 0;
}
```

При компиляции(cmake gcc) получаю:

```
 error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
 #define MAIN_ICON                       103
 note: in definition of macro 'MAIN_ICON'
 #define MAIN_ICON  103
```

Как правильно все это настроить?

Comment: Gcc такое не компилирует. Для этого используется компилятор ресурсов. Обычно он имеет имя rcc

Comment: У меня - `windres`.

Comment: Инклудить `.rc` никуда не надо. По идее, просто добавить его в CMakeLists в список сорцов, и надеяться что CMake разберется.

Comment: @KoVadim Можно подробнее как это реализовать?

Comment: @KoVadim получается с gcc никак не скомпилировать файлы ресурсов?

Comment: @Barev - gcc так не умеет. в принципе. Он не заморачивается на виндовые штуки. но с mingw вроде идет winres - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508242/how-to-compile-resource-file-with-mingw-windres и все может получится.

Comment: @KoVadim понял, спасибо